# Ubuntu 20.04 freezes instantly with kernel 5.8.0-45

Tags: boot, 20.04, kernel, freeze, gnome-session

When I ran `apt upgrade` yesterday it installed `linux-image-5.8.0-45-generic` in addition to `linux-image-5.8.0-44-generic`. But trying to reboot into this new kernel causes Ubuntu to freeze instantly on the first frame the cursor or the recovery menu is visible. I can't get into a terminal either using `Ctrl Alt F5` and the only responding things are the LEDs on my Keyboard toggeling when they should and a periodic flashing of the drive activity LED.

I disabled the splash-screen (by booting with 5.0.8-44 using advanced options in grub) to see the log and couldn't find anything red or any large error messages. Checking `/var/log/kern.log` afterward also didn't reveal anything odd, last messages are normal:

```
Mar 16 13:05:44 paul-linux-desktop kernel: [   19.812238] usb 3-2.3: 3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x84
Mar 16 13:05:44 paul-linux-desktop kernel: [   19.822302] usb 3-2.3: 3:1: cannot get freq at ep 0x84
Mar 16 13:05:46 paul-linux-desktop kernel: [   21.650038] rfkill: input handler disabled
```

Usually (with 5.8.0-44) these messages appear 10 [time unit] earlier and are followed by 2 more `rfkill: input handler en-/disabled` (and then a lot of `audit` messages)

I already tried to reinstall the kernel package without luck. I also found a few posts about Nvidia GPUs not liking this kernel, but I couldn't even get into recovery mode to disable any GPU things, so I presume this is not it.

My setup: Ubuntu 20.04 Lite dual-booting with UEFI of a SSD on an Intel i5 6600 with a Nvidia GTX 1060 attached to a HDMI display and a Logitech Mouse, PS2 Keyboard plugged into a USB 2.0 Adapter&Hub. Everything working fine using the 5.8.0-44 kernel.

Also: the "freeze" tag states I should just file a bug, but where and for what component? The log seems fine.

EDIT: journalctl revealed:

```
Mär 16 12:02:45 paul-linux-desktop gnome-session[955]: gnome-session-binary[955]: WARNING: Falling back to non-systemd startup procedure due to error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
Mär 16 12:02:45 paul-linux-desktop gnome-session-binary[955]: WARNING: Falling back to non-systemd startup procedure due to error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1
[...]
Mär 16 12:02:45 paul-linux-desktop gnome-session[955]: gnome-session-binary[955]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' exited with code 1
Mär 16 12:02:45 paul-linux-desktop gnome-session-binary[955]: Unrecoverable failure in required component org.gnome.Shell.desktop
Mär 16 12:02:45 paul-linux-desktop gnome-session-binary[955]: WARNING: App 'org.gnome.Shell.desktop' exited with code 1
Mär 16 12:06:03 paul-linux-desktop gdm-launch-environment][935]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session closed for user gdm
Mär 16 12:06:03 paul-linux-desktop gdm3[930]: GdmDisplay: Session never registered, failing
Mär 16 12:06:03 paul-linux-desktop systemd[1]: session-c1.scope: Succeeded.
Mär 16 12:06:03 paul-linux-desktop systemd-logind[665]: Session c1 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.
Mär 16 12:06:03 paul-linux-desktop systemd-logind[665]: Removed session c1.
Mär 16 12:06:03 paul-linux-desktop gdm3[930]: Child process -949 was already dead.
Mär 16 12:06:03 paul-linux-desktop systemd[1]: Received SIGRTMIN+21 from PID 324 (plymouthd).
Mär 16 12:06:03 paul-linux-desktop gdm3[1056]: Error: can't open /lib/modules/5.8.0-45-generic/updates/dkms
Mär 16 12:06:03 paul-linux-desktop gdm3[1056]: Error: can't open /lib/modules/5.8.0-45-generic/updates/dkms
```

Note that later there are a lot more complaints about `org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1` by various componests starting with g (`gsd-media-keys`, `gsd-sharing`...)

Answer (score 1):

I have also been having some problems in the past day which may be related to this kernel upgrade. I boot OK, but the system performance steadily deteriorates to become unusable. Reboot fails. When I review the crash with

```
journalctl -xb
```

I find fsck failure errors in the journal.
I have run

```
fsck -ACV -r
```

or
`fsck /dev/sda1`

(which is my /home location and the location of fsck failure errors in the journal), from emergency mode and found corrupted inodes which fsck has repaired so that the computer reboots again and seems normal for a while, but the cycle repeats. I thought since I was using Firefox and noticed deterioration in browsing performance that maybe Firefox was contributing, but I made a clean reinstall of Firefox and the problem persists.

I hope this might be helpful, but since you say the log seems fine, I have some doubt . . . maybe my problem is a coincidence and I just have a bad HD? Good luck to you.

Comment: Thanks I looked ate journalctl and posted my findings. I don't have nay fsck complaints, but It seems my gnome desktop crashes?

Comment: . . . turns out my issue WAS a failing HD. May yours be something else!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, very unsatisfying ending: another `apt update && apt upgrade` fixed it yesterday (or one of the unattended upgrades prior). The packages affected according to the log were:

```
linux-modules-nvidia-460-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 (5.8.0-45.51~20.04.1, 5.8.0-45.51~20.04.1+1)
linux-modules-nvidia-460-5.8.0-45-generic:amd64 (5.8.0-45.51~20.04.1, 5.8.0-45.51~20.04.1+1)
libsystemd0:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.4, 245.4-4ubuntu3.5)
udev:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.4, 245.4-4ubuntu3.5)
initramfs-tools-bin:amd64 (0.136ubuntu6.3, 0.136ubuntu6.4)
libudev1:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.4, 245.4-4ubuntu3.5)
systemd-timesyncd:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.4, 245.4-4ubuntu3.5)
systemd-sysv:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.4, 245.4-4ubuntu3.5)
libpam-systemd:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.4, 245.4-4ubuntu3.5)
systemd:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.4, 245.4-4ubuntu3.5)
libnss-systemd:amd64 (245.4-4ubuntu3.4, 245.4-4ubuntu3.5)
initramfs-tools-core:amd64 (0.136ubuntu6.3, 0.136ubuntu6.4)
initramfs-tools:amd64 (0.136ubuntu6.3, 0.136ubuntu6.4)
```

Note: I excluded a few more like firefox or telegram, as these shouldn't affect anything.

I heavily suspect `linux-modules-nvidia-460-5.8.0-45-generic:amd64` as the fix, as this seems like a very precise combination of versions.

Answer (score 0):

Try: `linux-modules-nvidia-460-generic-hwe-20.04 (5.8.0-48.54)`

https://packages.ubuntu.com/ru/groovy-updates/linux-modules-nvidia-460-generic-hwe-20.04

And/Or:

```
sudo apt reinstall *** for package
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt autoremove

reboot
```